# Assume the hypothesis $H_0 : u = 59$ by computing the relevant $p$-value

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

An observed sample of four observations from $N(u, \sigma^2)$ distribution has mean $54.75$ and standard deviation $10.21$. A table of quantiles of the chisquare distribution is given below

[image]

$(a)$ Assume the hypothesis $H_0 : u = 59$ by computing the relevant $p$-value

(b) Compute a $0.9$ confidence interval for $u$

(c) Compute an equal tail $0.9$-confidence interval for $\sigma^2$

ans:

(a) $pvalue = P(Z \leq \frac{\bar{x} - H_0}{\sigma_{0}/\sqrt{n}})$

$pvalue = P(Z \leq \frac{54.75-59}{10.21/2})$ (why is $\sqrt{n} = 2$?)

$P(Z \leq -0.832517401)$ (not sure what to do next)

(b) $CI = (\bar{x} \pm t_{\frac{1+r}{2}} \frac{\sigma_{0}}{\sqrt{n}})$

$=(54.75 \pm t_{\frac{1+0.9}{2}} \frac{10.21}{2})$ not sure how to get the CI from this

(c)

$$\left(\frac{(n-1)\sigma_0^2}{x^2_{n-1}\frac{1+r}{2}}, \frac{(n-1)\sigma_0^2}{x^2_{n-1}\frac{1-r}{2}} \right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{x^2_{3}\frac{1+0.95}{2}}, \frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{x^2_{3}\frac{1-0.9}{2}} \right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{3.127323}{x^2_{3}(0.95)}, \frac{3.127323}{x^2_{3}(0.05)} \right)$$

not sure how to solve for $x^2_{3}(0.05)$ and $x^2_{3}(0.95)$

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think 10.21 is supposed to be sample sd. If $\sigma^2$ is known, why construct a confidence interval for it? By your notation, you have assumed 10.21 is the known population sd.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. More that just notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all parts you must use special tables (software functions, online calculators)!

a) 
$$p\text{-value} = P\left(t \leq \frac{54.75-59}{10.21/2}\right)=P(t_{df=3}\le -0.8325)=0.2331\\
\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{4}=2, \ \text{(because the sample size is $4$)}$$
Note: Use [Student's t-table](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ822UZ822&biw=1440&bih=740&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=lIyUXK7KD8KmmwWb9674Dg&q=t%20table&oq=t%20table&gs_l=img.3..0j0i67j0j0i67j0j0i67j0l4.1081932.1082888..1083089...0.0..0.152.942.0j7......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39.ZRFd01nv1tY) or [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pr(t%3C-0.8325)%20where%20t%20~%20t%20distribution%20with%203%20dof) for: $P(t_{df=3}\le -0.8325)=0.2331$.

b) CC=$0.9$ (confidence coefficient).
$$CI = \left(\bar{x} \pm t_{\frac{1\color{red}-CC}{2},n-1} \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\left(54.75 \pm t_{\frac{1\color{red}-0.9}{2},3} \frac{10.21}{2}\right)=\left(54.75 \pm t_{0.05,3} \frac{10.21}{2}\right)=\\
\left(54.75 - 2.3534\frac{10.21}{2},54.75 + 2.3534 \frac{10.21}{2}\right)=
(42.74,66.76).$$
Note: Use [Student's t-table](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ822UZ822&biw=1440&bih=740&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=lIyUXK7KD8KmmwWb9674Dg&q=t%20table&oq=t%20table&gs_l=img.3..0j0i67j0j0i67j0j0i67j0l4.1081932.1082888..1083089...0.0..0.152.942.0j7......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39.ZRFd01nv1tY) or [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=5e0096402339448552f8dff7015d901d) for: $t_{0.05,3}=2.$

c) CC=$0.9$ (confidence coefficient).
$$\left(\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{\frac{1-CC}{2},n-1}}, \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{1-CC}{2},n-1}} \right)=
\left(\frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{\chi^2_{0.05,3}}, \frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{\chi^2_{0.95,3}} \right)=\\
\left(\frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{7.81}, \frac{3\cdot 10.21^2}{0.35} \right)=\left(40.04, 893.52 \right).$$
Note: Use [Chi-squared table](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ822UZ822&biw=1440&bih=740&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=CpuUXMTQOamFk74Po9OdsAw&q=chi-square%20table&oq=chi-square%20table&gs_l=img.3..0l7j0i7i30l3.153.428..876...0.0..0.234.547.0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.sm2fKPYKIEA) (or your post) or [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=9ad8d2e5f0a05a40a940d6b9c815967b) for: $\chi^2_{0.05,3, right}=\chi^2_{0.95,3, left}=0.35$.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** @Farruhola has provided numerical answers and some comments on mathods (+1). Because there seems to be some confusion about the CI for $\sigma^2,$ here is additional explanation for part (c). The data are normal, so you have
$$Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1 = 3).$$  Then find
quantiles .05 and .95 of this chi-squared distribution, $L$ and $R,$ respectively,
so that $L = 0.3519,\, U = 7.8147,$ according to the computation in R below.
(Can you find these two numbers, to three places, in the table you provided?)

```
qchisq(c(.05, .95), 3)
## 0.3518463 7.8147279
```

Thus $P(L < Q < U) = 0.90.$ The 90% CI for $\sigma^2$ is found by solving the inequality
in $L < Q < U$ to isolate $\sigma^2$ between bounds. Note that, after solving the inequality,  $U$ is used for the lower
bound and $L$ for the upper bound.

Check to make sure that the resulting numerical CI contains the point estimate $S^2$ of $\sigma^2.$
However, unlike the t confidence interval for $\mu,$ the point estimate is not at
the exact *center* of the interval. (That is, the CI for $\sigma^2$ is ***not*** of the form
"Point Estimate $\pm$ Margin of Error.")

Comment: +1, especially for the note "Note that, after solving the inequality, $U$ is used for the lower bound and $L$ for the upper bound".